# Помогите поправить запрос

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица wp_posts, которая хранит в себе post_type и post_parent

| ID | post_type | post_parent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | post | 0 |
| 2 | post | 0 |
| 3 | image | 1 |

Мне нужно сделать такой запрос, чтобы при запросе к post_type='post' я так же забирал все записи где post_parent = post.ID. Так же мне важно, чтобы каждый объект запроса содержал в себе что-то вроде ключа "attachments", где будут храниться дочерние записи. Вот что у меня получилось. Спасибо.

```
    SELECT p.*,
      JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(m.meta_key,m.meta_value)) AS meta
    FROM wp_posts AS p
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m 
      ON (m.post_id = p.ID )
      AND (m.meta_key='_aioseop_title' OR m.meta_key='_aioseop_description')
    LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_posts p2 
      ON p2.post_parent = p.ID
    WHERE post_type = 'post'
    AND post_status = 'publish'
    GROUP BY p.ID
    LIMIT 10
```

Ошибка: Column 'post_type' in where clause is ambiguous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После выборки у вас получается, что `post_type` есть как в `p`, так и в `p2` (а может это поле есть и в `wp_postmeta`, не знаю) и парсер не знает, какой из них надо брать. Нужно явно указать, например `p.post_type`/`p2.post_type`/`m.post_type` и т.д.... Аналогично может быть с `post_status`

ЗЫ: ambiguous переводится как "двусмысленный". На будущее)